# android listactivity and baseadapter

Tags: android, imageview, listactivity, baseadapter

I have a Listacitivty, where I need to show a image and text in every row.

The layout looks like this:

event.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="30px"
        android:layout_marginTop="2px" android:layout_marginRight="2px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2px" android:id="@+id/logoImage"
        >
    </ImageView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textSize="15px"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The activity looks like this:

```
  public class Activity extends ListActivity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        dba=new DatabaseAdapter(this);

        dba.open();

        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.addHeaderView(header);

        fillOnStart();
    }

    private void fillOnStart(){
        ArrayList<Title> temp = dba.returnTitle();    // this works

        ArrAdapter notes = new ArrAdapter(this, temp);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Size: " +notes.getCount(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();             
        //because this show good size


        setListAdapter(notes);         //i suppose this is a problem

        }
```

and my adapter looks like this:

```
 private class ArrAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private Context mContext;
        private ArrayList<Title> lista;

        public ArrAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Title> list){
            mContext = c;
            this.lista =list;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return lista.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //  ViewHolder vh =null;
            //Title title= al.get(position);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event, parent, false);

            ImageView imlogo = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.logoImage);
            TextView textTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tytul);

            textTitle.setText("asdasdasdasd");     //i try like that, to make sure that my databaseAdapter do not have blame on it

            convertView.setTag(v);


            return convertView; 
        }
    }
```

When i start app I see "...stopped unexpectedly..." - what am I missing?

### Update:

i don't use a logcat. WHen i run logcat and run program there is nothing in the table. maybe I do something wrong with logcat?

when i try to start logcat i get this messages:

```
[2011-11-23 10:26:30 - Logcat]device not found
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:736)
    at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:284)
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogPanel$3.run(LogPanel.java:527)
```

ok my listview show a text. this works View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event, null);,

but i don't see images in logoImage.

class title looks like:

```
public class Title {

    public int id;
    public String tit;
    public Bitmap logo;
    ... and setter and getter      

}
```

and method returns Arraylist (in dba) with Title look like that:

```
   public ArrayList<Title> returnTitle(){ 
            Title t = new Title(1,"aaaaaaaaaa", BitmapFactory.decodeFile("C:\\Users\\hormon\\Desktop\\favicon.ico"));
            Title t1 = new Title(2,"assdsdsdsdaa", BitmapFactory.decodeFile("C:\\Users\\hormon\\Desktop\\icon.ico"));

            ArrayList<Title> art = new ArrayList<Title>(2);
            art.add(t);
            art.add(t1);


            return  art;

        }
```

in otherhand, can I dynamically insert a images to fodler e.g. drawable-hdpi, and then insert to my imageLogo?

Comment: Can you post the errors that are thrown from LogCat?

Comment: Post the exception log, or stack trace

Comment: i don't use a logcat. WHen i run logcat and run program there is nothing in the table. maybe I do something wrong with logcat?

Comment: @Paresh Mayani: Thanks for the edit!

Comment: @BoltClock happy to help new SO member :)

Answer (score 0):

probably in getView you need to return "v" itself rather than using convertview.setTag(v). I think if you watch you logcat output, you might be getting NullPointerException as convertview itself will be null.

Comment: i try like that earlier, with the same result

Comment: View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event, parent, false); to    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event, null);   we dont use parent in getview